# determine from which file a function is defined in python

Tags: python, function, introspection

I am programmatically printing out a list of function in python.
I can get the name from `__name__`

```
for i, func in enumerate(list_of_functions):
    print(str(i) + func.__name__)
```

How to get the source filename where the function is defined as well?

and in case the function it is attribute of a object, how to get the type of parent object?

---

portability python2/3 is a must

Comment: The title says *"from which file a function is called"*, but you are actually asking *in which file a function is defined*, which is different...

Comment: will edit.you are right

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
func.__module__
```

Will return the module in which it is defined

```
func.__globals__['__file__']
```

will return the whole path of the file where it is defined. Only for user-defined functions

Answer (score 9):

> How to get the source filename where the function is defined ... ?

```
import inspect
inspect.getfile(func)
```

> and in case the function it is attribute of a object, how to get the type of parent object?

To get the class of a method (i.e. when the function is an attribute of a object):

```
if inspect.ismethod(func):
    the_class = func.__self__.__class__
```

ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html

Answer (score 2):

As stated here https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html `func.__globals__` returns the global namespace where the function was defined.

Answer (score 1):

For getting the filename just use -

```
print(os.path.basename(__file__))
```

if you want the full file path you can just use

```
print __file__
```

Comment: not quite. this will give me the filename of the current script. I am editing to clarify

Answer (score 0):

You can use `__file__` variable.

`print(__file__)`